# Why doesn't the with block in Python need the global keyword?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables, with-statement

I am using the `with` block to extract information from a file, and I am surprised that any variables declared in the `with` block are global. Shouldn't they be local to the `with` block, and shouldn't you need to use `global myVar` before changing global variables? After all, `with` defines a code block, right?

Comment: Consider `if...else` blocks and loops such as `while` and `for`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python doesn't have block scopes. The `with` statement does not introduce a new scope; the body of the statement is still in the same scope that has the `with` statement.

Python has 4 kinds of scopes:

1. The built-in scope, defining names available in any module without an explicit `import`.
2. Global scopes, one per module.
3. Non-local scopes
4. Local scopes: defined by a function.

No other construct defines a new scope: not `if` statements, not `for` or `while` loops, not `with` statements, not `try` statements, not `class` statements. Only things that define new functions (`def` statements, lambda expressions, and comprehensions) create new (local) scopes.

Every name first looks in the local scope (which may be the global scope if not inside a function definition), then in any non-local scopes (which may not exist, if a function is defined in the global scope, not another local scope), then the global scope, and finally in the built-in scope.

---

A non-local scope is just a scope that isn't the current local scope. For a module defined at the global scope, the closest enclosing non-local scope *is* the global scope.

But if a function is defined inside *another* function, then the closest enclosing non-local scope is the local scope in which the function is defined.

Functions can be nested fairly deeply, so there could be 0 or more additional local scopes between the current local scope and the global scope in which name lookups can occur. For example,

```
x1 = 'a'

def f1():
    x2 = 'b'
    def f2():
        x3 = 'c'
        def f3():
            x4 = 'd'
            print(x1 + x2 + x3 + x4)
        f3()
    f2()

f1()
```

The output of this mess would be `abcd`. When the argument to the `print` statement requires values for each of the four variables, each lookup starts in the local scope. Only a value for `x4` is found there; the other lookups extend into the nearest enclosing non-local scope, that of `f2`. A value for `x3` is found there, so the lookup for `x1` and `x2` extend to the *next* non-local scope, that of `f1`. `x2` is found, so `f1` extends another stop. Finally, a value for `x1` is found in the global scope.

So a non-local scope isn't so much a special kind of scope, just a name for a scope that isn't local to the currently executing function. It will either be the local scope of an enclosing function or the global scope.

Comment: So the only blocks that have new scopes are functions?

Comment: Correct. Two things to be aware of, though, are  `class` statements and comprehensions. A `class` statement defines a new *namespace*, but not a new scope. And comprehensions are implemented as anonymous functions, so they define a new scope where you may not have exepected one. E.g., `[int(x) for x in some_list]` defines `x` as local to an anonymous function that performs the iteration. `x` is no longer in scope outside the list (which was *not* the case in Python 2, by the way.)

Comment: Yes, and this is the same with for loops that use range, right? like `for i in range(10)`, the i is not saved a a global variable, right?

Comment: It may not be global, but the `for` loop does not create a new scope. `i` belongs to whatever scope contains the `for` statement, meaning `i` is still defined after the loop completes.

Comment: Oh, ok. So then if you want to delete the iterator after the for loop, you must `del i` after the for loop is over?

Comment: Yes, but there's rarely any need to do so.

Comment: @chepner you should add your comment about classes and comprehension to your already fine answer.

Comment: Can you give me some examples of a non-local scope? What is a non-local scope? I always thought there were only two: the global scope and the local scope.

Comment: @KrishnanShankar non-local scope is a local scope but not the most local scope (nested functions).

Answer (score 0):

A `with` statement does not create a scope (like `if, for and while` do not create a scope either).

As a result, Python will analyze the code and see that you made an assignment in the with statement, and thus that will make the variable assignment.

Initialization before the `with` scope can be safer in the sense that after the with statement we can safely assume that the variable exists. If on the other hand the variable should be assigned in the with statement, not initializing it before the with statement actually results in an additional check: Python will error if somehow the assignment was skipped in the with statement.